# Audio not working in 12.10

Tags: sound, 12.10, alsa

I did a clean install of 12.10. When I open Sound Settings in gnome the only device in the list is "Dummy Output", and sound is not working.

Sound worked fine out of the box in 12.04.

I ran alsamixer, it says my card is "HDA Intel", and chip is "Realtek ALC880". The alsamixer playback output was set to mute at first, unmuting did not fix.

I checked out the info at [unixmen](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/) as suggested on a similar question; I've done everything there except installing the ubuntu audio dev team driver. Should I try install this?

Edit:
I've been reading the [sound troubleshooting guide.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting)

It looks like Ubuntu is finding my audio device correctly.

```
mike@wucade:~$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Albatron Corp. Device 2668
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    Memory at d01c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

Still stuck as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Do you have `pulseaudio`? If you do, first `killall pulseaudio` and then try starting it again with `pulseaudio`

Comment: please, can you post the output of `aplay -l` ? And check if maybe an audio app locks the device by using it thru alsa directly (ex: hw:0,0) because it would prevents pulseaudio to open it. Remember pulseaudio uses alsa !

Comment: Install `pavucontrol` I have used this a few times to figure out problems with sound.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with the exact same device (Realtek ALC880)...and of course it's not as simple as checking "unmute" - did you ever resolve it?

Comment: If you have front headphone jacks, does it work if you plug headphones into them?  I did for me.

Answer (score 2):

Install `pavucontrol` (as [Rinzwind suggested in comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205055/audio-not-working-in-12-10/237048#comment279167_205055)). This can often directly facilitate *solving* the problem (not just troubleshooting it).

For example, I had this issue. `pavucontrol` revealed that my output on the Intel HDA device was disabled, and I was able to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I tick and untick the mute checkbox and it worked again.
Maybe it will be as simple as this for you ?

Comment: I wish it was this simple mate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reinstall in as the troubleshooting recommends you? I mean reinstall the drivers? It helped me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I logged into the terminal, checked the drivers I had others besides the dummy driver that I saw while connected via VNC in Rhythmbox. Ran a test on the speakers.  Went back to my VNC connection and it works.

Maybe it's a permission type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same mute problem.

I installed [pavucontrol [image: Install pavucontrol]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol), ran it, and clicked and unclicked the mute button -- voila -- audio working.